# jquery slider alternative?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, xhtml

Are there any alternatives to jquery-ui slider? It doesn't do what I want it to be (allow images to be used rather then the default css, well it does but the handle goes above the images).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't restyle the jQuery UI element to meet your needs (which I find unlikely - the HTML it produces is very, very bare-bones), then your needs are probably very specialized. I would recommend, then, that you make your own slider to meet your own needs.

Or, perhaps, you might run a quick Google search for "javascript slider" and find this lovely article on [30+ Javascript/Ajax Techniques for Sliders, Scrollers and Scrollbars](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html). Maybe one of them will produce the HTML you want.

Comment: The problem seems to be I am unable to figure out exactly how to do it. I managed to change the background and slider to the images, however the slider thing seems to be above the background, when I restore the normal css I see a - margin bot to make it go half way over the top/bottom. And I want to get rid of this. Is there a way?

Comment: @Steven - can we see a working example?

Comment: http://dubcanada.net/play/emma/jquery/index.html